# How can I repair the damage to this wood floor?

Tags: flooring

We just moved into a new house, and the flooring in the entrance and kitchen is a little beat up.  I am not sure if it is hardwood or laminate flooring.

There are some spare boards in the attic that are about 3/4" thick - they do not have a wood-looking layer on them, so I suspect they are not laminate.  The spares are much lighter in color than the ones on the floor.

Here is a picture of the damage:
[image: Floor Damage]

This is from the entrance where there are some dings and chips.  The floor in the kitchen has some of the shiny parts flaking off, but the wood itself doesn't appear to be damaged too much.

Is there a way to repair this type of damage?  Is there something I can do to maintain and protect the non-damaged boards?

Like I said, I do have spares, but since I have no flooring experience I would probably have to hire someone to replace the damaged boards.

Comment: Justin has it right, floor sanding is the way to fix this, but it means the whole floor, unless there is a good spot to stop the sanding at.

Comment: Nice - that was my question for Justin.  So this is most likely not laminate floor, correct?

Comment: If the house is older than 10 years it would not likely be a ENGINEERED wood floor, it is definitely not laminate.

Comment: The house was built in 2000, and I assume the flooring is original.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: looks like pretty standard 2 1/4" red oak hardwood.  engineered is usually no more than 1/2 to 5/8", traditional hardwood is 3/4" thick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesnt look too bad. I think when you sand the floor will take care of 95% of it. The clipping may need to be filled in with a little wood filler.
If it was me.. A nice runner or area rug in the entry would look nice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Do you think it is possible to sand just the affected areas and re-seal or re-stain those, or do you think the entire floor needs to be sanded and re-treated?

Comment: Assuming it is hardwood, which I think it is, you would need to sand and refinish the whole field. Doing a small area would leave it a different color (lighter).

Answer (score 2):

After sanding lemon juice will remove the grey spots that water damage had caused.just be sure to let it dry before staining.no amount of sanding will remove the grey or black spots caused by water damage.